# type "sf::View" does not provide a call operator error c++

Tags: c++, sfml

I get an error when I do this;

```
void ArcGame()
{
   cout << "HELLO";
}

if(sprite.getGlobalBounds().intersects(arcabnet.getGlobalBounds()) and sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
    {
        ArcGame();
    }
```

I get the error: Type "sf::View" does not provide a call operator. How do I fix this? I am using c++, sfml, and xcode, thanks.

Comment: I don't see any `sf::View` in your code, nor any call to a functor. We can't help you without seeing the code that actually fails.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The error is happening on the line that says ArcGame(); and I cant find out why, so I included this and I dont know what to show you without showing you the whole code.

Comment: Post the complete code. Always provide a [mcve]